# Sphinx, gettext and html : how can I create multiline translations?

Tags: python, html, python-sphinx

The documentation of my project (using Python 3.2) is created with Sphinx (1.1.3) and is made of HTML files. I have to write this documentation in English and in French; that's the reason why I build my documentation with Sphinx and gettext, using the usual bunch of .po(t) and .mo files.

By example, my .po files are made of lines like this one :

```
msgid "original text"
msgstr "translation"
```

My problem lies in the fact that if some translations are made of several lines, the corresponding HTML file loses the "new line" characters : my different lines are packed into one big paragraph. I tried different things, like :

```
msgid "original text"
msgstr "translation : first line \n second line"
```

But of course the HTML doesn't care about the \n character; same problem with the \r character.

Then I tried this :

```
msgid "original text"
msgstr "translation : first line <br> second line"
```

But all I get is something like `&lt;br&gt;` instead of the expected "line break". Same thing with `<br/>`.

What can I do ? I would be nice to help me !

Comment: This could help: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#how-to-indicate-a-line-break-or-a-significant-newline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, thank's to ms4py, I'm able to answer my own question :

- add the following line in each .rst file if you use "new line" characters in this file :

  .. |br| raw:: html

Then add an empty line, then add on a new line the following characters : "less than" and br />. Then a new empty line.

- use the following characters in each translations in order to have a break line : `|br|`  with spaces before and after `|br|`.

Thank you !